# Not able to see URL without trailing slash in NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I know that this is a common issue in NGINX and there are many threads about that.

Issue:

When accessing the URL **http://localhost/var** without trailing slash is working with my current config. However, I need to add 2 locations (one with trailing slash and second one without trailing slash).

If i try accessing the URL with trailing slash, it is being redirected correctly and page is displayed correctly.

The issue comes when i try accessing the second URL:

```
http://localhost/var/api/app/v2
```

I did the same, adding two locations (one with trailing slash and second one without trailing slash). However, looks like the rewrite that i included inside server block is making a conflict as the url has some stuff behind "var". I am getting an 404 error.

This is my **current** config file:

```
server {
        listen       8080;
        listen  [::]:8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
        absolute_redirect off;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;


        ##location 1##

        location /##var##/ {
            set $dash local.##var##.svc;
            rewrite ^/##var##(.*)$ $1 break;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://$dash:8080;
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/dash_auth;
        }


        location /##var## {
            set $dash local.##var##.svc;
            rewrite ^/##var##/(.*)$ $1 break;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://$dash:8080/;
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/dash_auth;
        }

         ##location 2##

        location /##var##/api/app/v2/ {
            set $nu local2.##var##.svc;
            rewrite ^/##var##/api/v2/app/(.*)$ /app/$1 break;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://$nu:6000;
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/dash_auth;
        }


        location /##var##/api/app/v2 {
            set $nu local2.##var##.svc;
            rewrite ^/##var##/api/app/v2(.*)$ /app/$1 break;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://$nu:6000/;
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/dash_auth;
        }


}
```

This is working when accessing the URL:

```
http://localhost/var
```

but not when accessing the URL:

```
http://localhost/var/api/app/v2
```

i think the conflict is regarding the rewrite in the server but not sure how can i fix that.

I tried to add the rewrite inside the location for /var/ but not working as expected. I was thinking about include a specifyc rewrite for every location but not sure if this is gonna work.

Also I trid to add these two rewite rules in server block, but not working:

```
rewrite ^/api/app/(.*)/$ /api/app/$1 permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
```

Regarding the ports, that is something currently working. i mean without including any modification in the nginx config it is working (just with URL with trailing slash although).

Comment: The config that you posted listen on port `8080` but your example URL (`https://localhost/var`) is using the default port (`443`). There is no way that the configuration you posted is powering that URL on the default port.

Comment: Sorry, already corrected. When not using port 8080 i am using 443. Do you have any idea how to fix that issue with two locations?

Comment: You edited https to http in your question, but that doesn't change my concern.  HTTP uses port 80 by default so you still wouldn't be hitting the service on port 8080 with that URL.

Comment: Well, i am using a container backend listening on port 8080 if that answer your question that is why i use proxy pass and port 8080. My question is more related to the locations

Comment: What do you have listening on port 80?  It doesn't look like the problem is with the configuration you have posted.

Comment: I cannot see anything listening on port 80 in any configuration in yamls. I am running this inside a container but i am not involved in the container itself. Basically I have a bunch of yamls files and i added this config for nginx. I do not see in any yaml for nginx port 80. May you please be more specyfic on what you would like me to check so i can troubleshoot a bit? I was sure that the issue was related to the location. As you can see including 2 locaons one without trailing slash and second one with triling slash it is working. Without trailing slash location page is blank. That's strange

Comment: Basically i would like to redirect trailing slash url with 301 code to non trailing slash location. I do not know what i should check to fix that. The thing is that when i remove location /##var##/ page is blank.

Comment: You need to find whatever is listening on port 80 before you can fix it.  The code that you have above can only affect URLs with the `:8080` in them.

Comment: I think i fixed that part. i will modify my original code and asking about another location as i fixed this but getting conflict with another location. Let me modiy the post.

Comment: please check the post again.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
proxy_pass http://$dash:8080;
```

To

```
proxy_pass http://$dash:8080/;
```

Also your default nginx location should looke like this

```
location / {
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/dash_auth;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://$dash:8080/;
}
```

Comment: Leaving that rewrite I am using on my original code i posted above and port redirect off too?

Comment: @XT you don't need to do anything, remove `port_in_redirect`, `rewrite` and anything else you've tried to beat this problem, just add `/` symbol after your port number in `proxy_pass` and use your normal config.

Comment: it is not working the trailing slash in proxy_pass. Getting the same error. redirected to "localhost:8080/var/" and impossible to show the page.

Comment: @XT please attach your *current* `nginx` configuration

Comment: i modified the first post with the current config just the block that is giving issues and server part.

Comment: @XT I've modified my answer too, check it please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244690/discussion-between-x-t-and-user973254).